# Older build version detection

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm working on a social game (actionscript) whenever I upload a build seems like for some users the new build isn't downloaded instead the older version (cached) is served to them. How can I detect the user is on an older version and perhaps throw a popup at them?

Comment: I use a config class and in it I put a build id.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is more about your web server configuration. Cache related headers to be more precise. But we at some point decided to solve this issue by publishing application####.swf upon each deployment, where #### is a build number. And updated the HTML wrapper accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

A little trick you can use is to append some FlashVars to the end of the embed code, e.g.

```
<embed src="file.swf?version=1.01" .. />
```

All you need to do is update the value of `version` each time you update the SWF.